# Installing another ubuntu version alongside an existing one

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning

I'm new to ubuntu!

I have decided I want to install ubuntu server on a different partition, I dont like virtual-box. Currenlty I have ubuntu 14 as the only OS on my PC. Please help me how I can accomplish the ubuntu server on a different partition and be able to choose which OS to work on at start-up.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: Follow the ubuntu install guide and ask questions if you have a specific problem